# Asymptotic variance of identically distributed but non-independent random variables

Tags: correlation, variance, central-limit-theorem, asymptotics

I have a question in computing the asymptotic variance of a sequence of random variables that is identically distributed but are not independent. Suppose we have a sequence of i.i.d. random variables $X_i$ such that its second moment is finite. Then, by the classical CLT, we know that $\sqrt{n} (\bar{X}_i - E[X_i])$ is asymptotically normal with variance $\text{Var}(X_i)$.

Now, if $X_i$ is correlated, my understanding is that we need to take $\text{Cov}(X_i, X_{i-1})$ into account in evaluating the asymptotic variance.

To make my question more concrete, let's suppose $X_i = 0.5\epsilon_i + \epsilon_{i-1}$ where $\epsilon_i$ is a sequence of i.i.d. normal random variables. Then, $X_i$ is a sequence of correlated random variables, with correlation $\text{Cov}(X_i, X_{i-1}) = \text{Cov}(0.5\epsilon_i + \epsilon_{i-1} + 0.5\epsilon_{i-1} + \epsilon_{i-1}) = 0.5$. May I know how should I incorporate this extra piece of information in computing the asymptotic variance of $X_i$? Is there a CLT that I can readily apply to characterize the exact distribution of $\sqrt{n}(\bar{X}_i - E[X_i])$? In particular, I would like to know the asymptotic variance.

Thank you!

Comment: Computing the variance does not require the CLT: it's purely a property of variances.  And because your $\epsilon_i$ are jointly Normal, you automatically know the standardized mean has a Normal distribution.

Comment: thanks @whuber. is this true even if I want to know the asymptotic variance? I just clarified the question a bit that I want to know the asymptotic variance of the limiting distribution. is the CLT not required here?

Comment: The CLT is unnecessary: every random variable you have written down has a Normal distribution and its parameters can be directly (and easily) computed from the information given.